# Исключение части юнит-тестов на CI

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, gradle, android-gradle, gitlab-ci

Суть проблемы: в Android-проекте имеются довольно длительные unit-тесты, которые не имеет смысла запускать при каждой сборке на CI (используется gitlab-ci), хочется выделить их отдельно и запускать время от времени самостоятельно. CI-скрипт запускает конкретный gradle-таск:

```
unit_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew testProductionDebugUnitTest
  ...
```

В связи с этим я предположил, что стоит создать некий новый task, который брал бы тесты из отдельной директории, куда я и сложил бы эти длительные тесты.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точный ответ на Ваш вопрос зависит от движка юнит-тестов.

Для JUnit рекомендуют использовать группировку при помощи `Categories` с последующим исключением.

```
// Маркер для временных тестов.
public interface SlowTests {
}

public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test1{
    }

    // Помечаем тест как медленный
    @Category(SlowTests.class)
    @Test
    public void test2{            
    }
} 

// "Точка входа" для тестов
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@ExcludeCategory(SlowTests.class)
@SuiteClasses(MyTest.class)
public class FastTestSuite {
}
```

P.S. Если я не ошибаюсь, то согласно замыслу CI/CD при сборке должны выполняться все тесты. Иначе это приведёт к ослаблению контроля качества со всеми вытекающими. Поэтому подобная экономия имеет смысл только при сборке "для внутреннего пользования" (на этапе разработки). Для продакшена лучше тестировать по полной программе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!